# How to verify the EventAggregator's unsubscribe method is called when disposing a ViewModel with Prism

Tags: wpf, prism, moq, eventaggregator

I'm struggling to write a test that confirms that I am correctly unsubscribing from an EventAggregator's message when it is closed. Anyone able to point out the (simple) answer?!

Here is the code:

```
public class ViewModel : BaseViewModel, IViewModel
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
    private SubscriptionToken token;
    IssuerSelectedEvent issuerSelectedEvent;

    public ViewModel(IView view, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        View = view;        

        issuerSelectedEvent = eventAggregator.GetEvent<IssuerSelectedEvent>();
        token = issuerSelectedEvent.Subscribe(SelectedIssuerChanged, true);            
    }

    private void SelectedIssuerChanged(IssuerSelectedCommand obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }

    public IView View { get; set; }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        issuerSelectedEvent.Unsubscribe(token);
    }
}
```

The test fails with:

> Moq.MockVerificationException : The following setups were not matched:
>   IssuerSelectedEvent x => x.Unsubscribe(It.IsAny())

Here is the test:

```
[Test]
public void UnsubscribeFromEventAggregatorOnDispose()
{            
    var view = new Mock<ICdsView>();
    var ea = new Mock<EventAggregator>();
    var evnt = new Mock<IssuerSelectedEvent>();

    evnt.Setup(x => x.Unsubscribe(It.IsAny<SubscriptionToken>()));

    var vm = new CdsIssuerScreenViewModel(view.Object, ea.Object);

    vm.Dispose();

    evnt.VerifyAll();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I am verifying that the `Unsubscribe` was called on the mocked `IssuerSelectedEvent`

```
[Test]
public void UnsubscribeFromEventAggregatorOnDispose()
{            
    var view = new Mock<ICdsView>();
    var ea = new Mock<IEventAggregator>();
    var evnt = new Mock<IssuerSelectedEvent>();

    ea.Setup(x => x.GetEvent<IssuerSelectedEvent>()).Returns(evnt.Object);

    var vm = new CdsIssuerScreenViewModel(view.Object, ea.Object);

    vm.Dispose();

    evnt.Verify(x => x.Unsubscribe(It.IsAny<SubscriptionToken>());
}
```

If you want to check that the exact same token is passed into the `Unsubscribe` then you will need a `Setup` for the `Subscribe` method that returns a token you create in your test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your `EventAggregator` mock to return your mocked `IssuerSelectedEvent`:

```
ea.Setup(x => x.GetEvent<IssuerSelectedEvent>()).Return(evnt.Object);
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried that before and got 
`System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.GetEvent<IssuerSelectedEvent>()`

Of course, I also needed to create a mock for IEventAggregator, not EventAggregator, so that now works

Answer (score 0):

The tests needs to be changed to:

```
[Test]
public void UnsubscribeFromEventAggregatorOnDispose()
{            
    var view = new Mock<ICdsView>();
    var ea = new Mock<IEventAggregator>();
    var evnt = new Mock<IssuerSelectedEvent>();

    ea.Setup(x => x.GetEvent<IssuerSelectedEvent>()).Returns(evnt.Object);
    evnt.Setup(x => x.Unsubscribe(It.IsAny<SubscriptionToken>()));

    var vm = new CdsIssuerScreenViewModel(view.Object, ea.Object);

    vm.Dispose();

    evnt.VerifyAll();
}
```